# Using If Else Statements To Notify user Of Results AJAX

Tags: php, ajax

I have a search function which executes on `keyup`. The messages could be

1. Shows loading when there are results
2. Reloads full table when user deletes values or does not add any chars to the search field. (This scenario recalls on the `displayRecords()` function.)
3. Tells the user there are no results.

I cannot seem to get the third scenario to work. My current code will shows "These are your search results..." and it will call the function to populate the table `displayRecords()` if the user deletes the chars they have entered. How can I get the program to take all 3 of my scenarios into its logic.

```
$("#itemID").keyup(function (){
    var url = searchPath;
    $.ajax({
        type  : "POST",
        async : false,
        url   : url,
        data: $('#itemID').serialize(),
        cache : false,
        success: function(html) {
           $( "#productResults" ).html( html );
        if (html === null) {
                  $("#loader_message").html('<p>There were no results that match your search criteria</p>').show();
              } else {
                  $("#loader_message").html('These are your search results... <img src="../wp-content/uploads/2016/02/loading.gif" alt="Loading">').show();
              }
        if( !$('#itemID').val() ) {                     
                displayRecords(limit, offset);   
            }
                html = null;
                window.busy = false;
            }
      });
});
```

Comment: may be your condition if (html === null) { is never met, as html might never be null...! what value does your 'html' variable has when there are no results..?

Comment: You are correct it is never null. I cant figure out how to handle that. Nothing is displayed in console.log and the if statement still wont fire off. So I assume some value exist that has to do wth ajax. but does not show up in the console when I console.log

Comment: wat does console.log(html); show when no results ...?

Comment: try changing your condition if (html === null) { .. to if ($.trim(html) === "") {...

Comment: PERFECT. Thank you! This worked. Please answer so I can accept it. Also does the rest of my logic look ok? Or would you change anything else about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

probably your variable html is not null, using [jQuery.trim()](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/) to remove extra whitespaces from your response data, so that you can check for emptiness, as

```
..
if ($.trim(html) === '') { //check if its blank
    $("#loader_message").html('<p>There were no results that match your search criteria</p>').show();
} else {
    $("#loader_message").html('These are your search results... <img src="../wp-content/uploads/2016/02/loading.gif" alt="Loading">').show();
}
..
```

Comment: Would you please add what exactly trim did here to make this work?

Comment: Thank you, so a whitespace could be in the html making it not null. I wonder why it adds a space when there is no date? weird.